# Java - Add to a string within a Lambda expression

Tags: java, foreach, lambda

I'm quite new to Java, I tried looking around on StackOverflow/Google but couldn't find an answer to my problem.

Problem: I have a String with the name of 's' that I have set to a sentence.
Then, I want to use the Lambda .forEach loop to iterate over a list of objects, retrieving the toString() from the objects and adding it to this 's' String.

This is my code:

```
public String toString() {
    String s =  "In klas " + this.klasCode + " zitten de volgende leerlingen:\n";
    deLeerlingen.forEach(leerlingen -> {
        s += leerlingen.toString();
    });
    return s;
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Directly using a `String` variable this way is not possible as lambda-external variables have to be [(effectively) final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#accessing-local-variables).

You can use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    b.append("In klas ");
    b.append(this.klasCode);
    b.append(" zitten de volgende leerlingen:\n");

    deLeerlingen.forEach(leerlingen -> {
        b.append(leerlingen.toString());
    });

    return b.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Follow up question. Is this really the shortest I can make it?:

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.append("In klas ");
        s.append(this.klasCode);
        s.append(" zitten de volgende leerlingen:\n");

        deLeerlingen.forEach(leerlingen -> {
            s.append(leerlingen.toString());
            s.append("\n");
        });
        return s.toString();

(Sorry, don't know how to make it code-formatted)

Comment: You could make use of the builder pattern and use `append` like `b.append("").append("").append("");` or you could use a method reference in the `forEach` instead of an explicit lambda: `deLeerlingen.forEach(b::append);`. But this is mere syntactic sugar - I doubt it would make the code execute faster. Use the version you can read and understand the best.

Answer (score 4):

```
public String toString() {
    String s =  "In klas " + this.klasCode + " zitten de volgende leerlingen:\n";
    String list = deLeerlingen.stream()
         .map(Object::toString)
         .collect(Collectors.joining());
    return s + list;
}
```